# Ajax-Error usando Json en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, json

estoy usando Json para hacer una insert en MySQL mediante ajax, pero no recibo resultado alguno y no se hace la inserción, ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

JS codigo

```
$("#btnprueba").click(function () {
            var array1 = [];
            $("#tabla .DataRow").each(function () {

                var firstTableData = {};
                var Aidi = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.ID_Articulo = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Descripcion = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Valor_Venta = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Subtotal = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text().trim();
                    array1.push(firstTableData);

            });

            var JsonValues = JSON.stringify(array1);
                alert(JsonValues);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GuardarDatosFactura2.php",
                data: "J="+JsonValues,
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.message);
                },

            });

        });
```

Json Obtenido en la variable JsonValues

```
[{"ID_Articulo":"001","Descripcion":"Caramelos","Valor_Venta":"6500","Cantidad":"2","Subtotal":"13000"}]
```

PHP codigo

```
?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$CON = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","BDfactura") or die ("error");

$data = json_decode($_POST['J'],false);

    $ID=$data->ID_Articulo;
    $Canti=$data->Cantidad;   
    $Vlr=$data->Valor_Venta;

    $cadena2 = "INSERT INTO ItemXVenta (IdArticulo, Cantidad, ValorVenta) VALUES ('$ID','$Canti','$Vlr')";
    $create2 = mysqli_query($CON,$cadena2);

    if($cadena2){
        $MSG= "Se guardaron los datos";
    }
    else{
        $MSG= "No se guardaron los datos";
    }
    echo($MSG);
```

?>

Comment: Prueba a cambiar data: "J="+JsonValues, por data: JsonValues, y puede que tengas que indicar el datatype: dataType: "json". Te recomiendo mirar los ejemplos de http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué es lo que ocurre al realizar click en tu elemento `#btnprueba`? ¿Este elemento de tu DOM es un boton tipo `submit`? ¿O es una etiqueta `<a></a>`?

Intenta con este código

```html
$("#btnprueba").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var array1 = [];
            $("#tabla .DataRow").each(function () {

                var firstTableData = {};
                var Aidi = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.ID_Articulo = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Descripcion = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Valor_Venta = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text().trim();
                    firstTableData.Subtotal = $(this).find('td').eq(4).text().trim();
                    array1.push(firstTableData);

            });

            var JsonValues = JSON.stringify(array1);
                alert(JsonValues);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GuardarDatosFactura2.php",
                data: "J="+JsonValues,
                success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.message);
                },

            });

        });
```

Con la linea de `e.preventDefault();` evitaremos el comportamiento natural de los input's tipo `submit`, ahora ya debería de desplegarse el `alert` o `console.log` que tienes dentro de tu `ajax`